# Can't Update! Repository has no release

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates

So, I am trying to update Ubuntu on my external HDD, but it doesn't update, and it shows this.
I tried to find something on Google, but no efficient results.
This is what `sudo apt-get update -y` returns:

[image: Update results]

Comment: Try searching this site, this problem comes up all the time.

Comment: It seems like a third party repository / PPA issue. If you follow the instructions in the linked post above, it should fix it.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste the text yourself into a browser, and I bet you'll find the PPA (3rd party software source where all checks are your responsibility) doesn't support your release, possibly is no longer maintained, or for some reason should not have been added (ie. checks were inadequately performed by person who added it).

Comment: If this is the PPA you mean - https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/pulp  the big clue "(Deprecated)" should have been a clue... support ending years ago. The description text reads "This PPA has been deprecated!!! .."   but I may have mistyped a key as you provided picture of text (not text)...